# How would I solve this ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My ODE looks as follows:

$(f(x))^2 + f(x)f'(x) x = c$

Any ideas if or how I could solve this?

I do know how to solve it for c=0 but Im not sure what the idea is for c $\neq$ 0

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$
$$
ff' = \frac{1}{2}\dfrac{d}{dx}f^2
$$
does this help?

$\textbf{update}$
$$
f^2 +xff' = f^2 +\frac{x}{2}\left(f^2\right)' = c
$$
make the sub $v = f^2$
$$
\frac{x}{2}v' + v = c
$$
thus solutions of the form
$$
v = c + \frac{\lambda}{x^2} = f^2 \implies\\
f = \pm\sqrt{c + \frac{\lambda}{x^2}  } = \pm\frac{\sqrt{cx^2+\lambda}}{x}
$$

Comment: It doesnt help with the c right? I could do it with 0 instead of c. But how do you get rid of the c?

Comment: You forgot the factor $x$ in the original ODE.

Comment: yep of course. Silly me!!